# Display Country, State, City, Area dynamically in tree view using php

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I have a tables like country , state, city , area and pincode. And i would like to display the country state city area and pincode like an tree structure below :

Example :

```
Checkbox All
          Checkbox India (country name)
              Checkbox Tamil Nadu (state name)
                 Checkbox Chennai (city name)
                    Checkbox Adayar (area name)
              Checkbox Delhi (state name)
              Checkbox Kerala (state name)
              Checkbox Karnataka (state name)
          Checkbox USA (country name)
```

While checked the india box the list of state under the country india will be expand as wise all.

Table Structure :

```
at_country : id,country
at_state : id,countryid,statename
at_city : id,countryid,stateid,city
at_area : id,countryid,stateid,cityid,area
```

How do i do this using codeigniter and php .

Advance thanks

Answer (score 1):

Visit this page for using tree view structure in jq UI

http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138128/Tree

You can use This by using AJAX[image]

Or you can download code from here
http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-treeview/

Thanks